# Вычленить кусок строки из строки по признакам

Tags: регулярные-выражения, парсер

Вопрос такой, как в C# просто и некодоемко можно спарсить строку вида _ * _ где * - любое кол-во символов

Например есть строка 
FIRST_SECOND_THIRD

Необходимо получить отдельную строку SECOND, самый простой вариант - использовать regular expresions насколько я знаю. С регулярками я на Вы, так что если не напрямую хотите отвечать дайте ссыль на доходчивое объяснение регулярных выражений.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cs
var all = "FIRST_SECOND_THIRD";
var second = all.Split('_')[1];
```